# React: Having some trouble passing multiple pieces of state.

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm pretty new react and trying to wrap my head around passing state to child components. In short I have a wrapper component which contains a child component which displays a table. Once I have my data stored in an array, I pass it to the child which then displays.

In the parent I pass an array like this:

```
 <CustomComponent data={this.state.arrayOne}/>
```

And can then access it with

```
 this.props.data.map((x,index) => .... etc
```

The issue is I multiple arrays I need to pass to the child. So if my state object looks like:

```
this.state = {
  arrayOne: [],
  arrayTwo: [],
  arrayThree: [],
}
```

how would I go about passing all three at once? Create and array of those arrays, and then if so how would I access them. this.props.data[0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are completely able to pass multiple props into a component!

`<CustomComponent array1={this.state.arrayOne} array2={this.state.arrayTwo}/>`

For code cleanliness I would make it even simpler and easy to read:

```
render() {
  const { arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree } = this.state;
  return (
    <CustomComponent
      arrayOne={arrayOne}
      arrayTwo={arrayOne}
      arrayThree={arrayThree}
    />
  );
};
```

---

If you really want it all as just the `this.props.data` then pass it as such:
`<CustomComponent data={ [...this.state.arrayOne, ...this.state.arrayTwo, ...this.state.arrayThree] } />` for one large array of all elements together.

or

`<CustomComponent data={ [this.state.arrayOne, this.state.arrayTwo, this.state.arrayThree] } />`
if you want to call `this.props.data[i]` to access each array separately but from one prop.

Comment: Ohh I can't believe I didn't think to just do that, it worked just as needed. I'd be curious what best practice would be?

Answer (score 1):

This approach usually means you're passing too many things to `<CustomComponent>` which leads to a single large component that's not very reusable.

Depending on your use-case, you may want to create "sub-components" that render each one of those arrays as a table:

```
<CustomContainer>
  <CustomTable data={this.state.arrayOne} />
  <CustomTable data={this.state.arrayTwo} />
  <CustomTable data={this.state.arrayThree} />
</CustomContainer>
```

Comment: Ya so in this case I get data to populate the child in the parent. I then pull out distinct data to populate a dropdown. So its the overall data and then the dropdown data otherwise I'd would be doing what you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

There are numerous ways to accomplish what you are asking.  I personally would just pass it as one object literal like so.

```js
//destructure the elements you want to pass
const { arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree } = this.state;

//pass the data prop as an object literal using property shorthand syntax
<CustomComponent data={{ arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree }}/>
```

And to access it use

```js
this.props.data.arrayOne.map(single => single);
this.props.data.arrayTwo.map(single => single);
this.props.data.arrayThree.map(single => single);
```